# Radio frequency

Tags: audio

I got a problem with my radio of Honda Accord Euro  2010. 
It’s not showing up AM frequency. 
FM is fine MW is fine but not AM (kHz). 
Can anyone please help me that What to do?
Thanks

Comment: Some radios don’t have AM any more...

Comment: MW radio *is* AM, at least in the UK. I don't understand what separate AM and MW options would be supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

The broadcast band is referred to as MW (Medium Wave). It is situated below the shortwave bands and the frequency range is usually between (but not always-globally) 530-1610Khz except in North America (US/Canada) where the upper frequency is 1710Khz.

In North America it is generically referred to as AM. AM and FM refer to the mode of transmission (Amplitude Modulation), FM is(Frequency Modulation) and not specific to any frequency range.

The FM broadcast band operates in a band known VHF(Very High Frequency)

However globally the channels are not always the same. Some countries are odd some are even. (99.9 , 100.6 Mhz) This is also true with the AM broadcast band (940, 791 Khz) .

All these differences in broadcast frequencies are set by international agreement to avoid interference with other countries and other users such as aircraft in the VHF.

Depending on where you are situated globally whether you country is even or odd. If this is the case then you are tuning in between stations.

On the other hand If I misread your question and it simply a misunderstanding of terminology. Hopefully my detailed answer clarifies everything and then some.